# PUT for encrypted files

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to be able to use PUT to copy encrypted files to an internal stage. I don't know of a way to provide any kind of encryption key as an argument to decrypt the file before copying, though. Is this possible to do? If it isn't, could this be added as a feature?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question.

Comment: There is no need pass an encrypted file to SnowSQL - your file will be encrypted / decrypted automatically when you use the PUT command.

Answer (score 0):

This actually is the automatic encryption used each time you upload a staged file to Snowflake Internal Stage:

- [Data Encryption](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-encryption.html)

Depending on where you will be staging your files, client-side encryption, ingestion encryption, and tri-secret secure, customer managed keys are all options.

For example, if you were using Amazon S3, you can create an encrypted stage: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-encryption.html#ingesting-client-side-encrypted-data-into-snowflake

There is also an enterprise feature for rotating keys called Periodic rekeying: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-encryption.html#periodic-rekeying

I hope these resources help you get started.